# suppose that $f :\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function, and that there exists $c>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\le c$ prove $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis

suppose that $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function, and that there exists $c > 0$ such that $|f'(x)|<=c \forall x \in \Bbb R$.prove that  $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y| \forall x,y \in $$\Bbb R$

Comment: mean value theorem

Answer (score 0):

For any interval $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we can find a point $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that 
$$
\bigg|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{a-b}\bigg|=|f'(x)|\leq C
$$
by the mean value theorem and by your assumption. Since this will hold for any interval you choose, you may conclude that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality 
$$
|f(b)-f(a)|\leq C|b-a| 
$$
holds.

Comment: I tried this but I thought it can't be that simple :(

Comment: why not? what troubles you?